# ItemViewModel item is null

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have class

```
  data class Patient(
  val  birthNumber: String ,
  val  firstName: String ,
  val  lastName: String ,
  val  birthDate: LocalDate ,
  val  healthInsurance: InsuranceCompany ,
  val  hospitalizations : List<Hospitalization> = emptyList()
)
```

wit itemViewmodel class

```
class PatientModel : ItemViewModel<Patient>() {
    val birthNumber = bind(Patient::birthNumber)
    val firstName = bind(Patient::firstName)
    val lastName = bind(Patient::lastName)
    val birthDate = bind(Patient::birthDate)
    val healthInsurance = bind(Patient::healthInsurance)
    val hospitalizations = bind(Patient::hospitalizations)
}
```

I'm trying to in my view bind data from textfields/combox to my PatientModel  object like this

```
 var model = PatientModel()
    val controller: AddPatientController by inject()
    override val root = VBox()

    init {
        title = "Pridat pacienta"

        with(root) {

            goHome()
            form {
                fieldset("Personal Information") {
                    field("First name") {
                        textfield().bind(model.firstName)
                    }

                    field("Last Name") {
                        textfield().bind(model.lastName)
                    }

                    field("birthNumber") {
                        textfield().bind(model.birthNumber)
                    }

                    field("InsuranceCompany") {
                        combobox<InsuranceCompany> {
                            items = controller.insuranceComp
                        }.bind(model.healthInsurance)
                    }
                    field("birthDate") {
                        datepicker().bind(model.birthDate)
                    }
```

But in the end when I call `model.item` it's null .

What do I have to do get the `data class Patient` object ? not the viewmodel one. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an `item` into the `ViewModel`. To give it a new instance, do `model.item = Patient(...)`. You don't necessarily need to do this before hand though.

A patient instance can also be passed to the `ViewModel` super constructor to automatically set the `item` property as well:

```
class PatientModel(patient: Patient) : ItemViewModel<Patient>(patient)
```

Be aware that you need a no args constructor to be able to use your viewmodel with injection though.

Since your `Patient` class is immutable, there is no way for the ViewModel to write data back into it automatically. To overcome this, override `onCommit` in the `ViewModel` and assign a new value to the `item` property, based on the values in the ViewModel properties at that time.

```
override fun onCommit() {
    item = Patient(birthNumber.value, ...)
}
```

JavaFX observable properties are intended to be used with mutable data structures, so you have to jump through a couple of extra hoops to use them with immutable values.